# how to execute the SSIS package with SQL server authentication in Azure SQL server virtual machine?

Tags: ssis, devops, azure-virtual-machine

I created simple SSIS package for copying the data from one table to other table with SQL server authentication. But I have SQL database in azure virtual machine.

The SSIS package will work successfully when I run in my local machine. After that I deployed SSIS package through the Devops flow like this below image.

[image]

After Release succeeded, then SSIS package will deployed successfully but when I execute the package it gives the error like this below figure.

[image]

can any one please tell me how to resolve this error as soon as possible?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the SSIS package to Ado.net connection and try. You may also try to change the password and check

Reduced the amount of data requested and the frequency.

Additional information:
Connecting to SQL Azure Database by using OLE DB is not supported.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx

Use ADO.NET source and ADO.Net destination in SSIS dataflow tasks to talk to SQL Azure through the SQL Client library. SSIS team added bulk insert support in SQL 2008 R2 to support bulk load to azure using ADO.Net only.